# How to include triangular Material Design AngularJS Admin Template to cg-angular generator,i want to build an app using the triangular template?

Tags: angularjs, triangular

I am a beginner in programming, I am trying to build an AngularJS application ,am using the generator 'cg-angular' using yeoman, i want to include triangular material design template to my AngularJS application.

Comment: Hello ,i found it better to use generator-gulp-angular instead of cg-angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do 2 things to get triangular runnning in your existing project

1) Load the triangular CSS and the extra packages CSS

2) Load the triangular Javascript and the extra packages Javascript

The code for these two steps are provided below.

We have created an example app that uses bower to run triangular, it can be found in the main download zip inside the extras/triangular-seed/ folder.

For Better understanding please follow triangular angular material documentation

[Triangular doc](http://help.oxygenna.com/angular/triangular/docs.html)